# Auto publish in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

In MyEclipse when i make changes in any jsps it is reflected automatically in the server without any needs to restart or republish the server.How can i do that with eclipse.
thanks

Answer (score 7):

In eclipse neon:

```
Window->Show View->Servers
```

then double click on server and in upper right corner, reveal Publishing section and there are three options:

- -"Never publish automatically"
- -"Automatically publish when resources change"
- -"Automatically publish after build event"